# How to add active class to html and remove it when is not viewed

Tags: jquery

I want to add active class to my website.there are a lot of section in my website .
i want to add active class to them when each section is veiwed and when is not viewed active class remove .

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".slide").addClass("active");

    });

</script>

<div class="slide" id="slide1" data-slide="1" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
<div class="seperator">
    <div id="second_pic" >
        <h1>تجربه ای متفاوت با تیم XETUDE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="float-right">

    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="slide" id="slide2" data-slide="2" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
<div class="wrapper">

</div>
```

any idea ?
thx in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "viewed" exactly, can you clarify?

Comment: sorry for bad describing ,the whole thing is i want to add active class to some sections and do some transition with css3 and when users click on another section active class being removed automaticlly

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".message").addClass("active")
         .mouseover(function() { $(this).removeClass("active"); });

});
```

Comment: I just add it to my code but active class not working @selman22

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add/remove the "active" class when the user hovers the object, then you can use the following snippet.

```
$(".message").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
)
```

Comment: thx , but i want to hide this after user click on another section , not hovering

Comment: how to define a context for this ?